# Limitation of Google Analytics Reporting API v4 Python

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to know the following:

1) I didn't found any dimensional limitation of of Google Analytics Reporting API v4 (only for v3 - 7 dimensions in any query). Does v4 have any limitations? Could you please share the link?

2) I've notice that v4 skips rows with null in at least one dimension. How to avoid it? How to result all rows?

Thank you in advance.